# What happens if the segment between two vertices of a polyhedron is the intersection of the polyhedron with a half-space?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I think that given any two vertices, say $x$ and $y$, of a convex polyhedron, if the line segment between $x$ and $y$ is the intersection of the polyhedron with a half-space, then $xy$ forms an edge. How do I formally prove this fact? I think that somehow I've to use convexity, but I'm not sure how. Please help.

Comment: I think this is true even for nonconvex polyhedra.